# Position divs on top of background image with relative position

Tags: css, html, imagemap

I have full-width div with a background image in it. The background image has people in it and I'd like to show a tooltip when you hover over each person.

I don't think you can write image maps with % widths so I'm trying to do this with DIVs. Something like this:

```
<div class="homepageimage">
<div class='artistmap' id='davidmap'></div>
<div class='artistmap' id='ceceliamap'></div>
<div class='artistmap' id='erinmap'></div>
<div class='artistmap' id='aimap'></div>
<div class='artistmap' id='tommap'></div>
</div>
```

and Css something like this:

```
.homepageimage{
 width:100%;
  max-width:2000px;
  height:750px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top:-50px;
 background: url({{ 'homepage_test2.jpg' | asset_url }});
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  clear:both;
  overflow:hidden;
 }

 .artistmap{
   height:100%;
   border:2px solid red;
   float:left;
 }

 .artistmap:hover{
  content:attr(title); 
 }

 #davidmap{
  width:10%; 
 }

 #ceceliamap{
   width:15%;
 }

 #erinmap{
  width:5%; 
 }

 #aimap{
    width:5%; 
 }     

 #tommap{
  width:10%; 
 }
```

Unfortunately depending on the size of the screen the divs won't line up with the people... What's the best way of solving this?

I posted the above code to cssdesk here:

http://cssdesk.com/vmZSD

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/G2HkS/) that might help you.

CSS

```
.americangothic {
    float: left;
    width: 315px;
    height: 384px;
    background: url(http://www.artic.edu/aic/collections/citi/images/standard/WebLarge/WebImg_000256/190741_3056034.jpg );
    background-size: 315px 384px;
    position: relative;
}
.changemediv1 {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px solid gray;
}
.changemediv2 {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid gray;
}

.face1:hover ~ .changemediv1  {
    background-color: green;
}
.face2:hover ~ .changemediv2  {
    background-color: green;
}
.face1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 35px;
}
.face2 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 130px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 180px;
}

img {
    width: 315px;
    height: 384px;
}
```

Just remember that all the divs need to be in the same container.

Comment: Hmm - thanks for posting. In your example though the image has a fixed size. In my example I'm trying to do the same but with a relative size (see img has width 100%). I'm not sure this will still work in that case (or I'm missing something). Thanks

Comment: I added a face1 div as per your code to my CSS and it changes position relative to the background image depending on the window size: http://cssdesk.com/vmZSD

Comment: Yep, that's a problem. Absolute positioning is required for a background image. You can't do a <map> on a background image. You might have to use some js.